# AMD Phenom II X6-1055T HEXA Core vs Intel i5-750 Quad Core

Tags: mysql, central-processing-unit

I have an option to choose between the 2 processors for a dedicated server.  Most of my sites use MySQL and Perl.  Other difference is that I get 8 GB of RAM with the AMD processor and 2GB with the Intel processor.  I expected be on the dedicated server for a year at least.

Can someone help which one I should go with and why?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not doing number-crunching and you use plural "sites". That points to the AMD setup for several reasons:

1. RAM. In and of itself 4x the amount of RAM is a winner for any DB use.
2. More cores. I don't think, that your major bottleneck is going to be CPU performance. More cores means that you can have more threads doing their work.

Comment: I will go with the AMD and see how it works out.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly just by the numbers I'd be going with the AMD. I'm not a DBA, nor am I intimately familiar with MySQl and Perl, other than running them the half dozen web servers I have in house. 1.5x more cores and 4x the ram just seem like where you'd want to be.

Answer (score 0):

Considering these three benchmarks, i would choose AMD Phenom II X6 1055T.

[Intel Core i5 750 vs AMD Phenom II X6 1055T](http://www.anandtech.com/bench/Product/109?vs=147)

[Intel Core i5 750  vs AMD Phenom II X6 1055T](http://cpuboss.com/cpus/Intel-Core-i5-750-vs-AMD-Phenom-II-X6-1055T)

[AMD Phenom II X6 1055T (95W) vs Intel Core i5-750](http://www.cpu-world.com/Compare/649/AMD_Phenom_II_X6_1055T_(95W)_vs_Intel_Core_i5_i5-750.html)